# delphi- sending by email

Tags: delphi, sendmail

I have XDbgrid and XDBcolumnsDialog and XQRgrid, all connected to a database view to allow the user to see his data and select which column to print/to show and to sort etc.

Now I want to email the user's selection from that same grid by exporting the file to the c drive and then attach it by email, using  this code

```
JvDBGridHTMLExport1.FileName:= 'c:\Items.html';
JvDBGridHTMLExport1.ExportGrid;
SendMailWithAttachments('', 'subject', 'body', 'c:\Items.html');
```

My problem is that:
`JvDBGridHTMLExport1` don’t work with `XDBgrid`, it only works with `DBgrid`
How do I solve this problem, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Please add code sample tags to the example code.

Comment: Hi there, have you resolved your problem somehow ? If so, please post your solution as the answer and accept it by your own. It might help to the others when they meet the same problem ;)